# Deploy S3Template.yml with Node.js and CloudFormation

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I have an s3Template.yml that I want to deploy using cloudformation.createStack.

There is a solution to this problem. To use a .sh script. - Not interested in that.

I am interested in doing it with Node.js

The template is tested using the command

```
aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://deployment-bucket-template.yml
```

I get positive result

```
{
    "Parameters": [
        {
            "ParameterKey": "DeploymentBucketName",
            "NoEcho": false
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my function:
The deployment bucket is in the same directory as the function.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region:'us-west-1'});
const path = require('path');

const credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: 'foo'});
const cloudformation = new AWS.CloudFormation();
const filePath = "./deployment-bucket-template.yml";


// Create the parameters for createStack
const stackParams= {
  StackName : "bucketnameblahblahblah",
  Parameters: [
    {
        ParameterKey: "DeploymentBucketName", 
        ParameterValue: "bucketnameblahblahblah"
    }
  ],
  TemplateBody: "file//:filePath",
  //also tried giving the path without the fancy stuff
  //TemplateBody: "file://./deployment-bucket-template.yml",
  //tried this too
  //TemplateBody: "file://deployment-bucket-template.yml",
};

cloudformation.createStack(stackParams, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

I expect my cloudformation.createStack to be deployed and an s3Bucket to be created.

I receive Error:

ValidationError: Template format error: unsupported structure.

Answer (score 1):

The `TemplateBody` property only allows you to define a CloudFormation template inline. Referencing a file (like in the CLI) is not supported by the SDK.

So in effect, you have to inline your template or load the file into a string before creating the stack.

```
// Create the parameters for createStack
const stackParams= {
  StackName : "bucketnameblahblahblah",
  TemplateBody: `AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      BucketName: bucketasfdsfdslahblahblah`,
};

cloudformation.createStack(stackParams, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, much apreciated. Your example works just fine. It took me some time to find a way to load the file, for that is what I wanted.
I'll post my answer.

I spend a lot of time thinking that I can specify the variable in which I've loaded like under BucketName have another Key:Value ``BucketBody: `${contents}` ``

Answer (score 0):

My answer to the solution:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const contents = fs.readFileSync('./template.yml')
const stackParams= {
 StackName : "bucketnameblahblahblah123frwrrwe",
  Parameters: [
    {
        ParameterKey: "DeploymentBucketName", 
        ParameterValue: "adjnadjnadladfafaad"
    }
  ],
  TemplateBody: `${contents}`
};
```

Next chalange would be to make this a function and use it to deploy it with serverless